# NameError: name 'sorting' is not defined

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am a newbie to Python and learning lists. I am unable to figure out the error in the following program (selection sorting of numbers):

```
final_input = []
while True:
          user_input = input("Enter number or quit: ")
          if user_input == "quit":
                    break
          final_input.append(user_input)
print(final_input)
sorting(final_input)

def sorting(final_input):
          count = 0
          while True:
                    final_output[count] = min(final_input)
                    final_input = final_input.remove(min(final_input))
                    count += 1
                    if count ==  len(final_input):
                              break
                    return(final_output)
```

Comment: Define your function before (in upper lines) you use it.

Comment: I was about post the same comment as @Rockybilly. But to expand a little: Python is interpreted so unlike some compilers the python interpreter only does one pass over the input so things need to exist when they are used.

Comment: python is interpreted language and you called `sorting` function before it defined

Comment: Side note:          why are you indenting **10 SPACES**? The convention is only 4.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Do you want us to explain lists? Do you want us to debug your code? Try to be clear as to what you're asking and what sort of answers you require. I debugged your code for you and I hope I helped, but if you make it clear what you want people to put, then it will be easier for us to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edited code:

```
def sorting(final_input):
          final_output=[]
          while 0 != len(final_input):
                    final_output+= [min(final_input)]
                    final_input.remove(min(final_input))
          return(final_output)
final_input = []
while True:
          user_input = input("Enter number or \"quit\": ")#
          if "quit"in user_input.lower():################## I only changed these lines because I feel the program is more neat like this.
                    break
          final_input.append(user_input)
print(final_input)
print(sorting(final_input))
```

I moved the function to the top, so it would be defined before it’s called.

In your function, you were trying to`final_output[count]=value`, to create a list. This doesn’t work in python. There are multiple “array like data structures”. Create an empty list like this: `final_output=[]`. You can then add to it by doing either `final_output+=[value]`, or `final_output.append(value)`. You can also do `final_output=[value1,value2,value3]` if you know what all the values are going to be when the list is created.

I added speech marks around “quit” as this prevents the string from being misinterpreted as “Enter number, or quit the program”, or ‘’’“Enter number or “quit:”’’’. I also made it so that it was no longer case sensitive, or punctuation sensitive.

## Result:

```
Enter number or "quit": 8
Enter number or "quit": 3
Enter number or "quit": 9
Enter number or "quit": 0
Enter number or "quit": Quit.
['8', '3', '9', '0']
['0', '3', '8', '9']
```

Is this the result you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Python is interpreted so you need to define things as they are used. Just change your code to this and it should work:

```
def sorting(final_input):
     count = 0
     while True:
          final_output[count] = min(final_input)
          final_input = final_input.remove(min(final_input))
          count += 1
          if count ==  len(final_input):
              break
          return(final_output)

final_input = []
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter number or quit: ")
    if user_input == "quit":
        break
    final_input.append(user_input)

print(final_input)
sorting(final_input)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.